# \csname if... in for loop

Tags: tex-core

Can somebody please explain, what's going wrong here:

```
\newcommand\@doctypes{apple,banana,pineapple}

\@for\@doctype:=\@doctypes\do{%
  \expandafter\newif\csname if\@doctype\endcsname
  \expandafter\def\csname\@doctype\endcsname#1{%
    \csname if\@doctype\endcsname#1\fi%
  }
}
```

It yields an `Argument of \@fornoop has an extra }` error

It's working fine without a foor loop

```
\def\@doctype{apple}

\expandafter\def\csname\@doctype\endcsname#1{%
  \csname if\@doctype\endcsname#1\fi%
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Is it possible to declare options in a loop?

```
\newcommand*\@doctypes{apple,banana,pineapple}

\@for\@doctype:=\@doctypes\do{%
  \expandafter\newif\csname if\@doctype\endcsname
  \expandafter\edef\csname\@doctype\endcsname#1{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname if\@doctype\endcsname#1%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname fi\endcsname%
  }
  \DeclareOption{\@doctype}{%
    \setdoctype{\@doctype}
  }
}

\newcommand*\setdoctype[1]{%
  \@for\@doctype:=\@doctypes\do{%
    \csname\@doctype false\endcsname
  }
  \csname#1true\endcsname
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the `\fi` in the replacement text that's not balanced by some `\if...` and so confuses the code for the loop.

You can do `\csname fi\endcsname`, so the `\fi` would not be seen; with `\edef` and expansion control, you get the required replacement text.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@doctypes{apple,banana,pineapple}

\@for\@doctype:=\@doctypes\do{%
  \expandafter\newif\csname if\@doctype\endcsname
  \expandafter\edef\csname\@doctype\endcsname#1{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname if\@doctype\endcsname
      #1%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname fi\endcsname
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

If you do `\show\apple`, you get

```
> \apple=macro:
#1->\ifapple #1\fi .
```

Here's a scheme for declaring options:

```
\ProvidesPackage{timt}

\newcommand*\timt@doctypes{apple,banana,pineapple}

\@for\timt@doctype:=\timt@doctypes\do{%
  \expandafter\newif\csname if\timt@doctype\endcsname
  \expandafter\edef\csname\timt@doctype\endcsname#1{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname if\timt@doctype\endcsname
      #1%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname fi\endcsname
  }
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\DeclareOption{\timt@doctype}{%
      \noexpand\setdoctype{\timt@doctype}%
    }
  }\x
}

\newcommand*\setdoctype[1]{%
  \@for\timt@doctype:=\timt@doctypes\do{%
    \csname\timt@doctype false\endcsname
  }%
  \csname#1true\endcsname
}

\ProcessOptions\relax
```

A test document is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[banana]{timt}

\begin{document}

\show\ifapple
\show\ifbanana
\show\ifpineapple
```

that issues

```
> \ifapple=\iffalse.
l.6 \show\ifapple

? 
> \ifbanana=\iftrue.
l.7 \show\ifbanana

? 
> \ifpineapple=\iffalse.
l.8 \show\ifpineapple
```

Comment: Can you also declare options in a loop? Please see the edit to my original question.

Comment: @TimT Added, if I understood well your needs.

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Could you please shed some light on why this is working. What is `\edef\x{\endgroup` this? Opening braces but \endgroup?

Comment: it seems to work also when I omit the `\begingroug... \endgroup`. What is the reason you used it? Thank you!

Comment: @TimT The only reason is not to leave `\x` defined.